# Closure of a set under a certain operation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

How can I prove that the set $A=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x>0\right\}$ is closed under the operation $\oplus$ defined by $x\oplus y=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}>0$ if $x,y>0$?

Comment: Firstly, do you know the definition of closure?

Comment: Mathematician 42: yes, x,y > 0

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

We want to show $A$ is closed under $\oplus$.

That is for all $x,y \in A$ we have $(x \oplus y)\in A$.

So let us take arbitrary $x,y \in A$ since $x,y \in A$ then we have $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x,y >0$.

Because of this we have $\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{y} >0$ and of course they are real.

Thus we must have that $x \oplus y= \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} > 0$ and is real so $(x \oplus y) \in A$ as required.